# Copying / Moving projects within SVN, losing Historical info?? Using TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a problem with Moving / Copying SVN from 1 branch to another for example, I seem to be losing historical details i.e. being able to look back at a current version

Can anyone help with regards to the process of Moving / Copying..... I presume Moving takes with it the history/version??  and Copying i presume doesn't ... very confused here...

I just moved a fairly large project from the trunk to a branch and now it doesn't show any of the version info for the files...

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Since you did not say what you did we can't tell you what you did wrong. Which client did you use to copy/move? Did you copy/moved the files in a working copy or directly in the repository ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper menu item to port changes between branches is **Merge**. It's an important concept that's explained in any decent Subversion manual.

Whatever, just copying or moving files should not make you lose your history *given that you do it with the appropriate Subversion commands*. There are basically two ways to use them from within TortoiseSVN:

- Drag files in Windows Explorer with the secondary mouse button and select "SVN Move..." or "SVN Copy...".
- Move files normally in Windows Explorer and [repair the damage](http://tortoisesvn.net/repairmoves.html) in the commit dialogue.

Further reference: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-rename.html

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you have checked `Stop on copy/rename` in the `Show Log` dialog of Tortoise?